# Make an @Embeddable class optional?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `DateInterval` class that is annotated with `@Embeddable` and it has two persistent fields, `startDate` and `endDate`. A `DateInterval` field may be optional depending on the persistent class that uses it. If the `DateInterval` field is optional, both of its `startDate` and `endDate` should be nullable.

How do I implement this with JPA 2 and/or Hibernate?

If I annotated directly the fields of the `DateInterval` as in the following, then ALL `DateInterval` fields would not be optional, which is clearly not what I want.

```
@Embeddable
class DateInterval {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public Date getStartDate() {
    }
}
```

I've tried the following, but didn't work.

```
class Foo {
@Embedded
@Column(nullable = true)
    public DateInterval getDateInterval() {
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [@AttributeOverride](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html) (only one column) or [@AttributeOverrides](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverrides.html) if more than one if you you to override default settings

Use instead

```
public class Foo {

    private DateInterval dateInterval;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="startDate", column=@Column(nullable=true)),
        @AttributeOverride(name="endDate", column=@Column(nullable=true))
    })
    public DateInterval getDateInterval() { return this.dateInterval; }
    public void setDateInterval(DateInterval dateInterval) { this.dateInterval = dateInterval; }

}
```